# Unstable WPA2 WiFi

Tags: intel-wireless

I have a WPA2 WiFi network at my place. My laptop has an unstable WiFi connection with the network. It randomly disconnects, and may or may not connect again. Some times it does not connect at all. Sometimes it disconnects whenever I attempt a relatively heavy download. I have linked two outputs of a diagnosis script.

Vaio running 16.04. Intel(R) Wireless WiFi 4965 driver for Linux.

Connected: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23288470/

Disconnected: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23288472/

How can make the connection more stable?

Comment: +1 For putting that output on http://paste.ubuntu.com ! That makes our lives easier, so we can spend time answering questions rather than editing horrible posts.

Comment: Thanks to the detailed report I can tell you the active AP is using a WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and TKIP, both not recommended. The recommended settings are: WPA2-AES only.

Comment: Note to acronym challenged like me, 'AP'='Access Point' which is your WiFi  router.